# Why is IE 7 allowing all my content to break past my DIV? (however it works in Chrome, Safari, etc)

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

If you use IE 7 and click on this site:

http://www.tlsadmin.com/tlsadmin/PortalHome.aspx

Then, navigate to:

TLS Admin
--\My Companies
------\Contoso
----------\Shared Contacts

You'll see how the list of contacts is all messed up and I can't scroll down.  Anyone know why?

And if you're curious, it's my job to take this site as-is and make it production ready :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see an issue with the scroll bar, but with the floated contact cards. Clear your float after all the cards.

```
<div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: white;" id="ContactsGridUserControl1_ContactsAsDIVCallback">
    <div class="outerContact">
        <div class="contactLarge"></div>    
    </div>
    <div class="outerContact">
        <div class="contactLarge"></div>    
    </div>
    <div class="outerContact">
        <div class="contactLarge"></div>    
    </div>  
    <!--Rest of cards...-->
    <br style="clear: left;" />
</div
```

Comment: @duriliai, I believe I added that line correctly, but IE7 is still acting wierd. What tool do you use to get the source since that's from a callback?

Comment: I use Firebug extension for FF.